# How to not hardcode a String in a software?

Tags: python, string, hardcoded

I'm wondering how it's possible to not hard-code a string, for example, an IP in some software, or in remote connection software.

I heared about a Cyber Security Expert which found the IP of someone who was hacking people in hes software, and with that they tracked him.

So, how can I avoid hardcoding my IP in to the software, and how do people find my IP if I do hardcode it?

Comment: This question is super broad at the moment, could you try to narrow it down?

Comment: Pass the string on the command line, or have the user enter it, or read it from a configuration file...

Comment: Well for starters what are you trying to do? What do you mean by not hardcode a string? If you are worried about someone tracking your ip, why not get a proxy server? Why need to hide your ip in the first place? Does your program need to download stuff from your ip or report something back to that ip? There's no detailed answer, only all general answers. Oh and if your program connects to an IP, we don't need to read the source, we can just see what our computer is connected to and follow that ip if needed.

Comment: Or am I even on the right track on what you want. Do you want someone not to know the "special str" in your program? or the value of the formula?

Comment: I'm not doing any program, i'm just wondering about this. the main question is how to hide a string or a variable in a program. The ip was an concret exemple. of course, you can use proxy, vpn, etc. but that's not the question

Comment: Then your answer is no. there is not way to "hide" a string value from someone who can run your code. Either they can get your source code, or run it line for line and find out what your comparing it to or what not. And why would you want to hide it in the first place. if your code is dealing with sensitive data, people you don't trust shouldn't have access to that code (running it).

Comment: """ I'm not doing any program, i'm just wondering about this. """
It could be dangerous for, for exemple, RSA encryptions keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to obscure a hard-coded string. One of the simplest is to XOR the bits with another string or a repeated constant. Thus you could have two hardcoded short arrays that, when XORed together, produce the string you want to obscure.

Comment: Thank you ! This is really realizable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide it, Encrypt it, you see this alot on github where people accidently post their aws keys or what not to github because they didnt use it as a "secret".
always encrypt important data, never use hardcoded values like ip as this can easily be changed, some sort of dns resolver can help to keep you on route.
in this specific case you mentioned using a DNS to point to a proxy will help to mask the endpoint ip.

Answer (score 0):

You could do any of these: 1) read the string from a file, 2) read the string from a database, 3) pass the string as a command line argument

Comment: I dont think this is what OP is looking for. OP wants to know how to cover his tracks in the program. IE If he gave you the program to run, he doesn't want his IP leaked...

Comment: But, if you read from any database, it show the DB credidential in your program, (and it can be readed ?), if you read a string from a file, you need for exemple a encrypted file, and to decrypt it, you need a decryption key in your program, (and it can be readed ? )

Comment: MooingRawr, no, i don't. I want to hide a String, or generally, a programm from being readed, especially for IP and RSA private key.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use asymmetric encryption, you can request the private string from a server using it (see SSL/TLS).
If you want to do it locally you should write/read to a file (OS should take care of authorization, by means of user access)

Comment: Thank. Can the key or any string requested by SSL/TLS from a server being intercepted when he come in the memory and he is used by the software ?

Comment: No, if rightly implemented SSL first confirms that the server is who he says it is (using asymmetric encryption, through a certificate authority), than your program and the server exchange a symmetric key for encryption using the same asymmetric encryption (this means only the owner of the server can decrypt the information, aka the symmetric key). All communication past this uses the symmetric key to encrypt the data, so it's not possible to intercept it (as long as the encryption algorithm is up to date).

Comment: Ok, the key cannot be intercepted in the Network, with MIM attack, for exemple, but when it come to memory, it's like if we define a variable ip = "myip" ?

Comment: Depends on the language you are programming, if it's a compiled language (like C or Java) the variable would only be in the memory, referred by a pointer, so it's almost impossible to read it. In interpreted languages (like JavaScript), it's possible read the variable, but it should be really hard if the variable is not in an accessible scope and your code is not human readable (if you use Uglify, for example).